# Ping sweep fast in python

Tags: python, ping, subnet

I have two ways to ping a network (using the python nettaddr library).

Option 1

```
from netaddr import *
from ping3 import ping
import subprocess


ip = IPNetwork('192.168.1.0/24')
print (list(ip))

for ip in IPNetwork('192.168.1.0/24'):

    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + str(ip))

    #and then check the response...
    if response == 0:
        print (ip, 'is up!')
    else:
        print (ip, 'is down!')
```

Option 2

```
for ip in IPNetwork('192.168.1.0/24'):

    response = subprocess.Popen("ping -c 1 " + str(ip),stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    response.wait()

    if response.poll()==0:

        print (ip)
```

The problem is that I find both of them very slow, for a /24 network they take about several minutes, and I would need it to be much faster.

Any simple and efficient way in python to do this?

Comment: you're not using ping python library but system calls.

Comment: You could use threads and ping them all at once or in chunks.

Comment: Doing *any* network operation sequentially is going to be slow. Even trivial network operations spend significant amount of time just waiting for replies. Use some form of concurrency, such as `threading`, `asyncio`, ..., to launch more pings while the first waits for reply.

Comment: This question has been asked several times. Looking for "python concurrent ping", e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993940/pinging-100-000-servers-is-multithreading-or-multiprocessing-better